# Data Binding / Data Conversion in Python

Tags: python, data-binding, grails, converters

Is there a Python lib to convert a bunch of strings to appropriate objects?

Web frameworks represent request data typically as map of the form `{ str : [str, ..]}` and I want to apply these string data structure to domain objects [like Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding) does:

```
def book = new Book(params) // params is from the request
```

or

```
book.properties = params
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you show looks similar to JSON (see e.g. the [json python module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)).

Quoting an example from its documentation:

```
import json
json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
```

gives you a nested structure of lists/dicts:

```
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```